# Infer Schema from REST service with SOAPUI

Tags: rest, xsd, soapui

I'm trying to infer a schema from a 3rd party REST web service in order to generate a cs to be used in an ASMX wrapper web service. I've created a REST Project in SOAPUI and am able to get multiple responses.

The Schema Conflicts are numerous and after Resolving Conflicts is performed there still remains many conflicts. There are no schema available on the Schema tab as it shows the Schema to be invalid.

I'm getting the following types of errors:

- Illegal complex content
- Element has undeclared child element
- Illegal content
- Element occurs less times than required
- Element occurs more times than is allowed

Is there any thing I can do or something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome these issues by switching to Liquid XML for the xsd generation from multiple xml files.
[Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/)